Inline Entity Form - how to set form field value in custom validate function
I have been struggling with this problem for few hours and I am unable to set form field values in a custom validate handler for an Inline Entity Form.
Inside _inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter hook, I have created a few form fields and registered a custom validate handler. Form fields will be used as placeholders to get user input and pass them to form fields (which are added as node fields in the backend), which are hidden.
In my validate handler, I can retrieve the user input data from $form_state. What I am unable to figure out is how to save these values inside the hidden form fields.
// These do not work.
$form_state[$field_name]['widget'][0]['value']['#value'] = $user_input_value;
$form_state->set($field_name, $user_input_value);
$form[$field_name]['widget'][0]['inline_entity_form']['#default_value'] = $user_input_value

Is it possible inside custom validate or submit function or is there any other way? Any help would be appreciated.

You used FormStateInterface::set which set a property usable in the code. Try using FormStateInterface::setValue instead, to set the value of a key (a field).
